# SharePoint farm admin not able to deploy solution

Tags: 2013, central-administration

I am trying to deploy a solution globally

I have added the solution using powershell

It is showing up under "Manage Farm Solutions"

When I open the solution and click on deploy now, it says access denied

I tried IISRESET but no luck

Have anyone faced this situation before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the user to

"`SharePoint_AdminContent_xx`" Database and did a IISRESET to resolve this issue

To do this, expand the DB -> Security->Users -> right click and select new user

Comment: Hi if ur provided solution worked for u, please mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try to run Central Administration as administrator, instead of browsing to central administration URL from a regular browser.

I was also trying to deploy the solution with CA opened in Chrome and getting Access Denied error.

I run IE as Administrator, opened the CA site in IE, deployed the solution and it worked as expected.